# Transits directions search

Tags: search-algorithms, search-problem

**Data Description :**

A database consisting of many **Transits**. Each transit has its own **Path** (both forward and backward), and each path has a set of **Stops**. Each stop consists of the position and the naming.

Each stop has a parent, for example, a 4-way intersection with a stop on each corner, where you can dismount transit X, and get on transit Y from the other side.

Each **Path**, forward or backward, is considered a unique path. (e.g, if 4 transits are present, the total number of Paths is 8).

**Input :**

2 points (**A** & **B**) on map, with latitude and longitude each. One is Source and one is Destination.

**Output :**

All possible routes between point **A** and point **B**, without duplicates (i.e, the same result with different info. Like Transit X then transit Y, but different intersection point).
For Example, one route might tell you to walk 50m to a transit that is crowded, while the other tells you to walk 200m to a transit that is relatively easier to find seats.

**Ideas so far :**

To find the direction, and transits to use, from point **A** to point **B**, do the following :

1- Find all stops that are around point **A**, using a calculation with the latitude and longitude.

2- Find all stops that are around point **B**, using a calculation with the latitude and longitude.

3- Get the paths for all transits that pass through all the stops around point **A**.

4- Go through all stops that are after the stops around point **A** in each of the transits, and find if any of them correspond to the stops around point **B**.

5- If no results are found, repeat steps 3 & 4 for each stop after the stops around point **A** in each of the transits, along with the stops that belong to the same parent (Finding the transits that pass through them, and checking if the stops after them in the path belong to the stops around point **B**, or a sibling to the stop), with a maximum of 4 transits deep (4 paths).

**Results :**

For finding a result that needs 2 transits to reach, the results are in average time (around 5 seconds).

But when the results needs 3 or more transits, the results take very long (around 30 seconds) if they find a result, and if the result is deep in the search, it can take minutes.

**Post Information :**

I'm not familiar with many search algorithms, but I don't think a tree would work here, as a tree is a set of known sources and destinations, whereas in this situation, I don't know the sources and destinations beforehand. And there are no weights for each of the paths down the tree.

And the way I'm using is the usual list search, without anything special or any optimizations, the only optimization is I don't search the same transit twice, and only search the stops after in the path.

**Question :**

What are possible implementations of such a search? What algorithms should I consider using?

**Live Examples :**

The Google Directions search.

**Post Script :**

I can't use the Google API because the data for the country I'm creating the search for isn't available in Google.

Comment: What is the problem statement?  You state an idea for an algorithm but I don't see what problem it is trying to solve, so I don't know how to make sense of it.  What are the inputs, and what are the desired outputs?

Comment: @D.W.Added input and output, hope that's enough.
The problem is optimization, finding a search function that is quick and reliable

Comment: Are you *sure* you want the algorithm to output all possible routes?  There may be exponentially many routes, so outputting all of them will be infeasible.  Many of them will be horrible.

Comment: Yes, because I want to leave it to the user to decide which suits them better.

Comment: The user isn't going to be able to inspect exponentially many routes.  You can't even print out exponentially many routes within the lifetime of the user.  I recommend that you re-examine your requirements or assumptions to figure out what problem you're actually trying to solve.